# How to reply to an annotation in PDF with Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, annotations, acrobat

I'm trying to write a javascript code to be run on the Acrobat Javascript console by referring to https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/acrobatsdk/pdfs/acrobatsdk_jsapiref.pdf but I've been unsuccessful so far.

What I'd like to know is how to reply to an annotation in javascript and I'm guessing the code should look like something below but I must be guessing all wrong. I'd appreciate your help. Thank you.

```
// create a new annotation and set it to a reply to the first annotation in a document.
var annots = this.getAnnots();
var myNAnnot = annots[0];
var repAnnot = this.addAnnot({
  page: myNAnnot.page,
  type: myNAnnot.type,
  contents: "Your comment is right."
});
repAnnot.refType = "R"; //should be "Group"??
repAnnot.inReplyTo = myNAnnot.name;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following will add a reply to the original annotation. Reply annotations must be of type "Text" since they don't show up on the page.

```
var firstAnnot = this.getAnnots()[0];
var repAnnot = this.addAnnot({
page: firstAnnot.page,
type: "Text",
contents: "Your comment is right.",
inReplyTo: firstAnnot.name
});
```

Comment: joel-san (sorry I don't know how to mention a name here), thank you for your reply. It works! I appreciate your help.